# after to close a dialog, the keyboard do not dissappear

Tags: android, dialog

hello i have an activity and i call a dialog from it. When the dialog appears i write something in an edittext and i click in the save button... the problem is that after to close the dialog and comeback to the activity the keyboard remains there¡¡

i have tried to do this solutions:

a) in the layout (xml):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

b) in the layout (xml):

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

c) in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

but this do not work...the keyboard do not dissappear after to dismiss the dialog.

some clue please to solve my problem?

my dialog code:

```
public class DialogCreamodListas extends Dialog
implements OnClickListener 
{
    static EditText etxLISTArecep;
    static EditText etxPRESUPUESTOrecep;
    ImageView mImageViewImagen1;
    ImageView mImageViewImagen2;
    Button btnAceptar;
    Context mContext;
    static Long ID_LISTA;
    static DbAdapter mDbHelper; 

    public DialogCreamodListas(Context context, long ID_LISTA, DbAdapter mDbHelper){    
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            final View view = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.dialogcreamodlist, null);
            setContentView(view);
            DialogCreamodListas.ID_LISTA = (long) ID_LISTA;
            DialogCreamodListas.mDbHelper = mDbHelper; 

            this.setTitle("Crea o modifica una lista");
            mImageViewImagen1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            mImageViewImagen1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mascarrito);
            mImageViewImagen2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image2);
            mImageViewImagen2.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit2);
            etxLISTArecep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxNombreLista);
            etxPRESUPUESTOrecep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxPresupuesto);
            CargaInformacion(); 

            btnAceptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_aceptar);

            btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(this);    
    }

    private void CargaInformacion()
    {
            if(ID_LISTA != null && ID_LISTA != -1)
            {
                    Cursor Lista = mDbHelper.RecuperaRegistros(DbAdapter.TABLA_LISTAS,ID_LISTA);
                    ((Activity) mContext).startManagingCursor(Lista);
                    etxLISTArecep.setText(Lista.getString(Lista.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.LISTA)));
                    etxPRESUPUESTOrecep.setText(Lista.getString(Lista.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.PRESUPUESTO)));
            }
    }    

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnAceptar) 
            {
                //AQUI RECUPERO LOS DATOS Y ALMACENO EN BBDD 
                GuardaDatos();
                CargarDatos();
                dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }   

        public static void GuardaDatos()
        {
            try
            {
            String[] Valores;

            if(ID_LISTA == null || ID_LISTA == -1)
            {
                Valores = new String[]{null,etxLISTArecep.getText().toString(),etxPRESUPUESTOrecep.getText().toString()};
                long id= mDbHelper.creaRegistro(DbAdapter.TABLA_LISTAS,Valores);
                if(id>0)
                {
                    ID_LISTA=id;
                }
            }
            else
            {   Valores = new String[]{ID_LISTA.toString(),etxLISTArecep.getText().toString(),etxPRESUPUESTOrecep.getText().toString()};    
                mDbHelper.actualizaRegistro(DbAdapter.TABLA_LISTAS,Valores);
            }   
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
                Log.e("EditaListas","Error: "+E);
            }
        }   

        public void CargarDatos()
        {
            if (this.mContext instanceof AdminListas)   
            {
                ((AdminListas) this.mContext).CargaDatos();
            }
            else
            {   
                Cursor ListaCursor=  mDbHelper.RecuperaRegistrosTabla(DbAdapter.VISTA_LISTAS);
                ((Activity) this.mContext).startManagingCursor(ListaCursor);        
                String[] Origen = new String[]{DbAdapter.LISTA,DbAdapter.PRESUPUESTO,DbAdapter.ARTICULOS,DbAdapter.DIFERENCIA};
                int [] Destino = new int[]{R.id.txvnombrelista,R.id.txvpresupuesto,R.id.txvarticulos,R.id.txvdiferencia};       
                SimpleCursorAdapter listas = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getContext(),R.layout.registrodetallelista,ListaCursor,Origen,Destino);       
                ((ListActivity) this.mContext).setListAdapter(listas);  
                }
        }


}
```

Comment: Where is your dialog code? I think you may be overriding the dismiss yourself!

Comment: i have edit the post with the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

To manually close the soft keyboard you can do this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Where `editText` is the EditText your soft keyboard is currently interacting with.

Comment: when i place the code in my .java i get an error compilation getSystemService is not defined into my dialog. i supose this work for activities but how can i to make work getSystemService in my dialog?

Comment: ok at the end this is the code that compile but dont work :((  `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etxLISTArecep.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Answer (score 0):

to make dissapear the keyborad it is necesary to remove the follow parameter in the activity that call to your dialog in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode...
```

i had this that is supposed that hide the keyboard

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

but when i have removed the entire line it works¡¡¡¡¡¡: